# Parse a string to a date gives a wrong date

Tags: python, date, datetime-parsing

I'm trying to parse a string to a date in this format : `%Y%m%d%H%M%S` by this code :

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as parseDate
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

chaine = "01/10/201604:45:00"
print chaine
date = chaine[:10] + " " + chaine[11:]
print date
date = parseDate(date,yearfirst=True)
print date
i = str(date).replace('-','')
print i
i = str(i).replace(':','')
print i
i = str(i).replace(' ','')
print i
```

This is what I get as output:

```
01/10/201604:45:00
01/10/2016 4:45:00
2016-01-10 04:45:00
20160110 04:45:00
20160110 044500
20160110044500
```

Here, instead of getting 01 as the day and 10 as the month, i get 01 as month and 10 as day, meaning I get january instead of october. 
In the other hand, when I change the `chaine` to : `14/11/201615:30:00` I get the correct date: `20161114053000` : month then day.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html

Comment: @MartijnPieters: ok, thanks. still feel that things that are not in the standard library should be imported in the questions...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: I agree, and the renamed function wasn't helping either. The dateutil project is quite popular for this sort of parsing, which is the only reason I knew about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to achieve that:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> datetime.strptime('01/10/201604:45:00', '%d/%m/%Y%H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 4, 45)
```

Comment: Sure, but `dateutil.parser` is a *flexible* parser that can handle different input formats at the same time, which is why it is often used instead of `datetime.strptime()` (which can only handle one specific input format at a time).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I got it. I think when we have just one format, it is not required to install a new package (`python-dateutil`) ;)

Comment: Nope, but since the OP asked about *that specific function*, I assumed they had reason to use it. As it turns out, perhaps they had not.

Comment: @Cloudgls: can I ask, why did you use `dateutil` for this problem then? I had made the (obviously wrong) assumption that you needed dateutil because your input was more varied than just this one example.

Answer (score 2):

Your date is ambiguous; it can either be interpreted as the first of October or the 10th of January.

Because the first number in your input (`01`) is the *day*, not the month, you need to set the `dayfirst` argument to `True`; by default this is set to `False`, meaning the first number encountered is interpreted as the month:

```
>>> parseDate('01/10/2016 4:45:00')
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 10, 4, 45)
>>> parseDate('01/10/2016 4:45:00', dayfirst=True)
datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 1, 4, 45)
```

Comment: But I want to get the month first in my case

Comment: @Cloudgls: no, then `01` would mean January. In the *input* `01` comes first. You state in your question that this date represents *October*, so you want the *second* number to be the month, the first number is the day. Are you confusing this with the output?